# PyQT: QFileDialog keeps on opening window after clicking on cancel or ok

Tags: python, pyqgis, pyqt

I use to write QGis plugins, which is based on PyQT.
I use to create QButtons and connect their click to a function that itself calls a QFileDialog.

For example:

```
def doOpenFile(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.dlg, self.tr("Open input file") )
        if fname:
            self.dlg.editInFile.setText(fname)

    # ____________
    def doInitGUI(self):
        # connect buttons
        self.dlg.buttonInFile.clicked.connect( self.doOpenFile )
```

So: I click on a button, which triggers a QFileDialog interface.
Quite ofter (but not always, and I could not define the conditions), the QFileDialog will re-open itself after clicking on "OK" or "Cancel". It requires me to cancel several times to stop the QFileDialog re-opening.
I suppose that the click event is thrown several times, is it correct?
How can I solve this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to use `getOpenFileName` without these parameters.

I've done this before with:

```
dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog()
fname = dialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Import JSON", "", "JSON files (*.json)")
```

and I've never had any problems like yours.

Comment: I just tried it, and I still have the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My problem came from the fact that I was calling self.doInitGUI from the run() method of my plugin, therefore the connect function was called every time I ran my code. I moved the initialisation of the connections (the call to self.doInitGui) at the end of the add_action() method, which is called only one time, and I do not have this problem anymore.