# Qt folder browser opening more than once in QGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I have a Qt plugin, and i have a button `browse_btn` to browse for an output folder. 
I use the `QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory` function and it all works fine. However if I close the plugin and open it again, then click the pushbutton to add a path, the opened window for choosing the path will re-open after I choose a path or close it. If I close the plugin a open it again the 'choose path' window will reopen 3 time and so on...

The similar problem [is still open here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171395/pyqt-qfiledialog-keeps-on-opening-window-after-clicking-on-cancel-or-ok) and [in comments here](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html) and probably [solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840502/qt-folder-browser-opening-more-than-once), but since there is no code provided I cannot apply it to solve my problem.

The exact code is following:

```
self.dlg.browse_btn.clicked.connect(self.set_output)

def set_output(self):
    folder_path = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self.dlg, u"Pick a folder"))
    if not folder_path:
        return None
```

I think this happens because each time I open-close the plugin the separate connection is created with `self.dlg.browse_btn.clicked.connect(self.set_output)`, and it only disconnects after I relaunch QGIS or use [Plugin Reloader](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugin_reloader/)

Comment: My guess is you would need to disconnect the signal when closing your plugin. If you built your plugin using the **Plugin Builder**, there should be a `onClosePlugin()` function inside your main python file (i.e. _pluginName.py_). Here you should disconnect your function using `self.dlg.browse_btn.clicked.disconnect(self.set_output)`.